# access control don't work correctly symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony

I have problem with the access control , I have access to some route as /Acceuil even if I am not logged in !! 
This is normally the problem in the security.yml
**security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
         ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_ADMIN ,ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN


    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email


    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: /acceuil
            # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                 # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:      
                target: /login
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register/etudiant, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register/entreprise, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY     }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/acceuil/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/gestion/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

can you help me please ?

Comment: Is the path (route) actually `/Acceuil` with a capitol **A**?

Comment: main:
    pattern: .*

Comment: Remove the last slash. Because `^/acceuil/`will not match `/acceuil`
Btw, you made a typo on the name, it's `accueil`

Comment: @Amitsouko thanks  a lot it works well :D